# Join a new organization in a channel. Hyperledger Fabric Node-sdk

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to join a new organization in a channel of an existing network.
I understood the flow to join an org to a channel from [fabric documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html) but they did use docker.

I want to accomplish the same using node-sdk.

To get the latest config block of a channel I am using these methods:

```
<async> getChannelConfig(target, timeout)  
<async> getChannelConfigFromOrderer()
```

https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/Channel.html#getChannelConfig__anchor
Both are returning the same result. And its type is **common.ConfigEnvelope**.
It is not **common.Block**.

It is returning an object according to documentation and I am saving it as a json file.
When I went through it, It doesn't have the below fields which are required for the purpose.
`{"channel_group":{"groups":{"Application":{"groups": {`
I am attaching the latest block [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16XzcWjATzkTYHkh55opg6m-h2nqv-_QD) which I got.

Please tell where I am making the mistake and if there is any reference for this please mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the latest config blocks are protobuf object.

So, when I am trying to save it as json, it was not properly formatted for json.

To do that, first, it has to convert into buffer and save.

```
// return latest config block as protobuf object

const latestConfig = await getChannelConfigFromOrderer();

const latestConfigBuffer = latestConfig.toBuffer();

// save it in .pb format  
fs.writeFileSync("latest-config.pb", latestConfigBuffer);
```

Then using configtxlator convert it to json and made changes accordingly.